# How to query two set of parameters using couchbase SearchQuery

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++

I am using couchbase java-client version 2.5.4 and jdk 1.8. I want to query with AND and OR operators in the single query. But am unable to do this.

users:

```
firstname       lastname    age    gender 
Ani             Mary        12     Female
John            William     16     Male
John            William     12     Male
John            Sam         13     Male
```

I want to query like the following using searchQuery with conjuctions and dijunctions instead of N1qlQuery

```
select * 
from `users` 
where 
   (firstname="john" and lastname="william" and age = "12") or
   (firstname="ani" and age="12" and gender="female")
```

The java code,

```
Map<String, String> userParams1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
userParams1.put(“firstname”, “john”)
userParams1.put(“lastname”, “william”)
userParams1.put(“age”, “12”)

Map<String, String> userParams2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
userParams2.put(“firstname”, “ani”)
userParams2.put(“gender”, “female”)
userParams2.put(“age”, “12”)

 List<MatchPhraseQuery> queryforUserParams1 new ArrayList<MatchPhraseQuery>();
        List<MatchPhraseQuery> queryforUserParams2 = new ArrayList<MatchPhraseQuery>();

        for (Entry<String, String> userParam : userParams1.entrySet()) {
            MatchPhraseQuery query = SearchQuery.matchPhrase(userParam.getValue()).field(userParam.getKey());
            queryforUserParams1.add(query);
        }

        for (Entry<String, String> userParam : userParams2.entrySet()) {
            String key = userParam.getKey();
            String value = userParam.getValue();

            MatchPhraseQuery query = SearchQuery.matchPhrase(value).field(key);
            queryforUserParams2.add(query);
        }

AbstractFtsQuery[] queries1 = queryforUserParams1.toArray(new AbstractFtsQuery[queryforUserParams1.size()]);
        AbstractFtsQuery[] queries2 = queryforUserParams2.toArray(new AbstractFtsQuery[queryforUserParams2.size()]);

        ConjunctionQuery query = SearchQuery.conjuncts(queries1).and(SearchQuery.disjuncts(queries2));
        System.out.println("QUERY: " + query);

        bucket = couchbaseCluster.openBucket(“users”);
        SearchQueryResult result = bucket.query(new SearchQuery("users_fts", query));
        System.out.println("RESULT: " + result);
```

logs:

> QUERY:
>   {"conjuncts":[{"field":"firstname","match_phrase":"john"},{"field":"lastname","match_phrase":"william"},{"field":"age","match_phrase":"12"},{"disjuncts":[{"field":"firstname","match_phrase":"ani"},{"field":"gender","match_phrase":"female"},{"field":"age","match_phrase":"12"}]}]}
>
> Feb 09, 2018 11:08:32 AM com.couchbase.client.core.node.CouchbaseNode
>   signalConnected INFO: Connected to Node localhost/localhost Feb 09,
>   2018 11:08:32 AM
>   com.couchbase.client.core.config.DefaultConfigurationProvider$8 call
>
> INFO: Opened bucket users RESULT: DefaultSearchQueryResult{error=null,
>   status=DefaultSearchStatus{totalCount=6, errorCount=0,
>   successCount=6}, hits=[], errors=[], facets={},
>   metrics=DefaultSearchMetrics{took=1006179, totalHits=0, maxScore=0.0}}

The result will be like the following,
users:

```
firstname       lastname    age    gender 
Ani             Mary        12     Female
John            William     12     Male
```

How to write a code to get this result in couchbase SearchQuery with conjunction and disjunctions?

Comment: I'm not clear, is this a N1QL question or a Full Text Search question? If it's FTS, please post the index you've created.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is strictly Java related, I think it's the N1QL query. Based on the query you wrote and the sample data you've given, I believe you have two things you need to change.

1. `where firstname="john"` - According to your sample data, the value is "John" not "john". So your query won't match (it's case sensitive).
2. `and age = "12"` - I'm assuming your sample data is storing age as an integer, not a string. "12" is not the same as 12.

Try running this query instead:

```
select * 
from `users`
where 
   (firstname="John" and lastname="William" and age = 12) or
   (firstname="Ani" and age=12 and gender="Female");
```